# How to read xml file with binary data into Matlab? (VTK/VTU File)

Tags: xml, matlab, file-io, binaryfiles

I would like to be able to read in an xml formal file which has a section containing binary data. An example file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="1941" NumberOfCells="11339">
      <PointData>
        <DataArray type="Float64" Name="magnetic field strength" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" offset="0"/>
        <DataArray type="Float64" Name="magnetic flux density" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" offset="46588"/>
        <DataArray type="Float64" Name="magnetic vector potential" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" offset="93176"/>
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="GeometryIds" format="appended" offset="139764"/>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" offset="185124"/>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="appended" offset="231712"/>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="appended" offset="403396"/>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="types" format="appended" offset="448756"/>
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
<AppendedData encoding="raw">
_�XF@�Loû1q@�`@!?�V7^W@9�D�C�z@�b�d@���Y�b@�r <snip>
</AppendedData>
</VTKFile>
```

This is a VTK data file, specifically the unstructured gid type, for which the .vtu extension is used. The format of this is normal xml, but with a section 'AppendedData' where there is an underscore followed by binary data, the xml describes where each of the data sequences start and end in this data.

Matlab's `xmlread` can't read this file, I presume because of the binary portion. I get the error below:

```
[Fatal Error] elmer_3d_magnet_mesh.dat0001.vtu:24:1: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Error using xmlread (line 97)
Java exception occurred:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/rcrozier/Sync/cad_models/elmer_3D_magnet/elmer_3d_magnet_mesh/elmer_3d_magnet_mesh.dat0001.vtu; lineNumber: 24;
columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

However, I can successfully read in the xml portion of the file (using `fgetl` to read up to the `AppendedData` tag). I can then create a temporary xml flie by adding the missing closing tags and reading this in using `xmlread`. I can then parse the xml to determine the data structure. This just leaves the reading in the binary portion part. At the end of reading the xml data `fgetl` leaves me at the file position corresponding to the start of the line with the underscore.

How can I ignore the underscore character, then read in the binary data?

Actually it is the 'ignoring the underscore character' part that is proving difficult as I can't figure out out how to do this without knowing about the character encoding of the file (<s>UTF-8 in this case</s> I don't know the encoding, `file -bi` returns `application/xml; charset=binary` on one example).

In case it's of interest, the actual vtk file format specification can be found [here (pdf)](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf)

**EDIT**: The code to get the xml part with `fgetl`

```matlab
% open the file
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

% close file when we're done
CC = onCleanup (@() fclose(fid));

xmlstrs = {fgetl(fid)};

find = 1;

while ischar (xmlstrs{find})

    find = find + 1;

    xmlstrs{find,1} = fgetl(fid);

    if ~isempty(strfind (xmlstrs{find,1}, 'AppendedData'))

        xmlstrs = [ xmlstrs; {'</AppendedData>'; '</VTKFile>'} ];

        % could get file position like this? how many bytes?
        datapos = ftell (fid) + 4;

        break;
    end

end
```

Comment: could you please add the code with the fgetl you wrote

Comment: @Finn, I've added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to determining the position was to calculate the character bit length from the first line read in like so:

```
% open the file
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

% close file when we're done
CC = onCleanup (@() fclose(fid));

xmlstrs = {fgetl(fid)};

firstlinebytes = ftell (fid) - 1;

bytesperchar = round (firstlinebytes / numel (xmlstrs{1}));
```

then the position of the first byte in the data section is

```
datapos = ftell (fid) + bytesperchar;
```

Note, that this isn't the whole answer to reading 'raw' type data in the AppendedData section which is poorly documented. You will find more info on the format of 'raw' (rather than 'base64') data [here](http://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2007-October/006064.html), but the short answer is it's encoded like the following:

```
_NNNN<data>NNNN<data>NNNN<data>
 ^         ^         ^
 1         2         3

where each "NNNN" is an unsigned 32-bit integer, and <data> consists of
a number of bytes equal to the preceding NNNN value.  The corresponding
DataArray elements must have format="appended" and offset attributes
equal to the following:

1.) offset="0"
2.) offset="(4+NNNN1)"
3.) offset="(4+NNNN1+4+NNNN2)"
```